# Unable to configure a Salesforce Authentication Provider because there is no 'Auth. Provider' option in Quick Find box?

Tags: authentication, connected-apps, apexrest

I am trying to [Configure a Salesforce Authentication Provider](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_sfdc.htm) but am stuck at "1. From Setup, enter Auth. Providers in the Quick Find box, then select Auth. Providers."

I have tried 'Authentication Provider', 'Auth. Provider', 'Auth Provider' in the Quick Find box but no dice. There is 'Identity Provider' which I don't think this is.

I was able to do this though: "To set up the authentication provider in your org, you need the values from the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret fields of the connected app definition."

I am on the unlimited edition. Can some one please tell what I am missing? Perhaps this feature has been renamed/moved since the time of the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find Auth Providers under Setup->Administer->Security Controls, it's the node between Single Sign On and Identity Providers. If you don't see it there, log a case with Salesforce.com. Those docs are correct and up to date, so support may need to intervene here.

Comment: It is missing. Thanks for the info. Can you guess what special access I will need to have that option enabled or why it doesn't show for me at all? I am already an Admin.

Comment: If you have the "Configure Application" permission you should see it. Support can help out further from there.

Comment: Mind telling me where to find the 'Configure Application' setting? I want to make sure I don't have it enabled before reaching out to support.

Comment: The Configure Application permission is set on the profile.

Answer (score 1):

On Profile->System Administration -> Enable Manage Auth. Providers

[image]